# How to wait for page load for any browser

Tags: hp-uft

During test run, multiple tabs get opened in chrome. As it is opening the new tabs, I would like UFT to wait until complete page loads. I am trying to make it a standard wait without waiting for a specific object.

For example, during run chrome opened, launched URL, click a link, new tab opened, now for the new page to load. Then click a link from 2nd tab and wait for the 3rd page to be loaded.

How can I force UFT to wait for the last page loaded assuming there are multiple tabs?

Comment: Loop through each `Browser` object and check that they are loaded before you carry on?

Comment: Yes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will wait till all page is downloaded.

```
Browser().Page().Sync
```

This will wait for particular object

```
Browser().Page().Object().Waitproperty
```

If you want for property of object(s) to change, loop it, like

```
Do Until WaitProperty = Argument
    print "Wait. Progress "&Progress
    wait 3 'wait 3 seconds
    Progress = Progress+"." 'add a period to show progress
    Set ObjColl = MyBrowser.ChildObjects(WObj) 
    WaitProperty = cstr(ObjColl(t).GetROProperty(Arg4)) 'get the object property
Loop
```

To loop through all pages in a browser:

```
'Get Pages count:
Set browserObject = Description.Create
browserObject("micclass").Value = "Browser"    
GetBrowserCount = Desktop.ChildObjects(browserObject).Count

'loop and sync (or any other methods):
for i = 0 to GetBrowserCount-1
browser().page("micclass:=Page","CreationTime:="&i,"Title:=.*").Sync
next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Sync for each browser opened also you can use .WaitProperty "visible","true" in order to wait for a property of an object displayed.